# Complex numbers and Roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I have no clue how to begin these problems. How do I start? I don't think I should pound em out...Thanks.

Let P be the set of $42^{\text{nd}}$ roots of unity, and let Q be the set of $70^{\text{th}} $ roots of unity. How many elements do P and Q have in common?

Let P be the set of $42^{\text{nd}} $roots of unity, and let Q be the set of $70^{\text{th}} $roots of unity. What is the smallest positive integer n for which all the elements in P and all the elements in Q are $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity?

Comment: For the second question, are you asking for the smallest integer $n$ such that $P\cup Q$ is the set of $n$-th roots of unity?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614012/proof-that-mathbb-g-n-bigcap-mathbb-g-m-mathbb-g-mn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question is the same as asking for which positive integers $k<42$ and $n<70$ do we have $\dfrac{2\pi}{42}k=\dfrac{2\pi}{70}n\iff5k=3n$. The second is equivalent to determining the least common multiple of $42$ and $70$, which is $210$.

Comment: I tried the first question and had 13 positive integers, but that is incorrect. Any further hints?

Comment: @MathisLife: I assume you got a bit confused by the word *positive*. In my country, which has historically been influenced by the [French](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki) system, it includes $0$.

Comment: Oh, I see. If we include $0$...would there be 14 positive integers then?

Comment: @Lucian: I meant to say *12 positive integers.

Comment: @MathyPerson: I suggest that you revise your computations.

Comment: @Lucian: I recalculated. 9 positive integers, including $0$?

Comment: @MathisLife: It is beyond me how on earth you obtain such odd results. Can you at least write down the general solution for the Diophantine equation $5k=3n$ ? This way maybe we'll be able to tell what went wrong with your computations.

Answer (score 1):

The $n$-th roots of unity $\omega^{(k)}_n$ are 
\begin{equation}
\omega^{(k)}_n = \exp\left(2\pi i k\over n\right) \mathrm{~for~} k=0,1,\ldots, n-1~.
\end{equation}
As some examples, for $n=2$, we have the roots $\omega^{(0)}_2=1$ and $\omega^{(1)}_2=-1$. Now, note for $n=4$, we have $\omega^{(2)}_4=-1$. There is a root in common here because $1/2 = 2/4$, *i.e.* the ration of $k/n$ is the same for these two roots (actually there is another common root, since $\omega^{(0)}_n = 1$ for all $n$). In fact, its clear from the formula for the $\omega$ that
\begin{equation}
\omega^{(k)}_{n} = \omega^{(l)}_m
\end{equation}
whenever ${k\over n} = {l \over m}$. So, given $n=72$ and $m=40$, you just have to figure out how many ways you can satisfy this relationship with integers $0 \le k < n$ and $0\le l < m$. Hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

So, we have $$x^{72}-1=0\text{ and }x^{70}-1=0$$

From [Prove that $\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1),  $$(x^{72}-1=0,x^{70}-1)=x^{(72,70)-1}=x^2-1$$