# Primitive roots of unity

Tags: roots-of-unity, primitive-roots

Let $R$ be the set of primitive $42^{\text{nd}}$ roots of unity, and let $S$ be the set of primitive $70^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity. How many elements do $R$ and $S$ have in common?

How would you work this out?

Thanks

Comment: $n/42=m/70\Longrightarrow n/m=42/70=3/5$ and $n=3k$; $0\le n < 42$; and we have 14 elements

Comment: This question/post would not be a duplicate since this is the problem relating to **primitive** roots of unity. The other post linked relates to the non-primitive roots of unity. Instead, this should be linked: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648822/complex-numbers-and-primitive-roots-of-unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any *primitive* $42$-th root of unity has order $42$. Any primitive $70$-th root of unity has order $70$. So the sets $R$ and $S$ are disjoint.

We get something more interesting if we ask how many complex numbers are simultaneously a $42$-th root of unity and a $70$-th root of unity (there are $\gcd(42,70)$ of them).

Comment: Good conciseness, clear and net.